# Сгенерировать HTML-элементы по нажатию radio-button

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-form, jquery-form

Помогите, пожалуйста, реализовать задачку.
 Есть форма, в которой две радио кнопки, которые должны по выбору генерировать разный html-код. При этом, если пользователь начинает играться с переключением кнопок, должен оставаться только код соответствующего контейнера, а код ненужного - удалятся.
По сути нет разницы: будет решение реализовано на `JS` или `jQuery`.
Нужен тупо без ошибок рабочий вариант.

```js
function requestNumber(a) {
  var customData = a.value;
  if (customData == "firstRequest") {
    document.getElementById("customerRequest").removeChild('div');
    document.createElement('div').addClass('firstRequest').innerHTML =
    '
    "\n\n" +
    "<div id='firstTimeRequest'>\n" +
       "<legend>Информация</legend>\n" +
       "<div class='form-group'>\n" +
          "<label for='' class='col-sm-3 control-label'>Ваш возраст *</label>\n" +
          "<div class='col-sm-9'>\n" +
             "<input type='text' class='form-control' name='' value=''>\n" +
             "<p class='help-block'>Укажите цифрой количество полных лет</p>\n" +
          "</div>\n" +
       "</div>\n" +
     "</div>\n";

  } else if (customData == "notFirstRequest") {
    document.getElementById("customerRequest").removeChild('div');
    document.createElement("div").addClass("notFirstRequest").innerHTML = "\n\n" +
      "<div id='notFirstRequest'>\n" +
      "<legend>Информация</legend>\n" +
         "<div class='form-group'>\n" +
            "<label class='col-sm-3 control-label'>Выберите производителя *</label>\n" +
            "<div class='col-sm-9'>\n" +
               "<select type='text' class='form-control' name='' value=''>\n" +
                  "<option value='0' disabled selected>Выбрать..</option>\n" +
                  "<option value='1'>Вариант 1</option>\n" +
                  "<option value='2'>Вариант 2</option>\n" +
                  "<option value='3'>Затрудняюсь с ответом</option>\n" +
               "</select>\n" +
               "<p class='help-block'>Выберите вариант ответа из списка</p>\n" +
            "</div>\n" +
         "</div>\n" +
      "</div>\n";
  }
}
```

```html
<form action="" class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Вы обращаетесь *</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <div class="radio">
        <label><input type="radio" name="requestType" id="requestType1" value="firstRequest" onChange="requestNumber(this)">Обращаюсь первично</label>
      </div>
      <div class="radio">
        <label><input type="radio" name="requestType" id="requestType2" value="notFirstRequest" onChange="requestNumber(this)">Обращаюсь не в первый раз</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="customerRequest">
    <div class="firstRequest"></div>
    <div class="notFirstRequest"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3">
      <button class="btn btn-warning btn-lg" type="submit">Отправить</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var tabsContent = [
  '<select name="select1"><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option></select>',
  '<select name="select2"><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3" selected >3</option></select>'
];

$('.tabs [type=radio]').change(function(){
  var index = $(this).index();
  $(this).parents('.tabs').find('.tabs__content').html(tabsContent[index]);
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.tabs [type=radio]:checked').trigger('change');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tabs">
  <div class="tabs__head">
    <input type="radio" name="tabs" checked />
    <input type="radio" name="tabs" />
  </div>
  <div class="tabs__content">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Таким путём получится скрыть ненужный контент от пользователя, но при этом он остаётся в теле страницы. Форма так или иначе будет обрабатывать эти поля, если отдельным скриптом не повлиять на те же input'ы для удаления атрибутов name и value. Мне необходимо отдать форме на обработку только востребованные name'ы и полученные от пользователя value, чтоб скомпоновать письмо. Если знаете решение, пожалуйста, подскажите. И отдельное спасибо, что уделили мне время)

Comment: @eflangner , тогда так

Comment: Оно. Вот прям, как надо. Спасибо)

Comment: Подскажите, в чём фокус? Только сегодня обнаружил и пока не допетрил: как победить? Если input'ы обернуть в отдельные контейнеры (div, label и банальный br), отделив их тем самым друг от друга, показывает только первый элемент массива, а переключения не происходит?

Comment: @eflangner , в этом случае неверно определяется `var index`. Например: `input[type=radio]` обёрнут в `label`, тогда `var index = $(this).parent('label').index()`

Comment: @eflangner  Если ответ вам был полезен, отметьте его плюсом и/ или галочкой рядом с цифрой ответа